# shifting a DataFrame along another and mapping correlation

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataset full of meaningless information (length=M), within which a range with the data I am actually looking for is hidden. Since I know in advance how the "true data" section approximately looks like, I have a "master dataset" (length=n, whereby n is way smaller than M), which I shift along the measured dataset. The logic I use is:

1. I start by comparing the master dataset with the first n elements of the measured data
2. calculate the correlation
3. Shift in the measured dataset by one element. Compare the master dataset with the measured data [1:n+1]
4. calculate the correlation
5. shift by another element. Correlation with  measured data [2:n+2]
6. and so on...

This way, I can locate my data by finding the maximum correlation between the data and the master. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
a_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
b_list = [6,7,8,7,6]
a_array = np.array(a_list)
b_array = np.array(b_list)

a_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(a_array)
b_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(b_array)

correlations = []
for i in range (0,len(a_dataframe)-len(b_dataframe)):
    correlations.append(a_dataframe[i:len(b_dataframe)+i].corrwith(b_dataframe)[0])
```

This code works just fine (although the correlations that come out in this example are nonsense), and it finds what I look for. The problem  have is that shifting each time one element with a loop and appending each calculated correlation to a list seems like a pretty inefficient approach to me. And this step is actually one of the bottlenecks of my whole software when it comes to calculation time.

I am searching for more efficient, elegant, pythonic apporaches to basically do the same. Help?

Thank you very much in advance

D.

#### EDIT AFTER SCOTT THOPSON'S COMMENT

I have corrected the mistake pointed out.

Comment: IN this line: correlations.append(a_dataframe[i:len(b_dataframe)+i].corrwith(a_dataframe)[0])  Should that be b_dataframe instead of a_dataframe inside corrwith?

Comment: Yes Scott Boston, you are right. Thanks for your input. I made the mistake when writing the simplified example. Luckily in the original program everythin is as it should be :)